# What to do in relation to pension funds when leaving Canada?

Tags: eu, canada, pension

A Canadian friend of mine, who lived all his life in Canada, is about to permanently move to the European Union. What would happen with his Canadian pension if he decides to stay in Europe?

Answer (score 1):

Pension == Public Employee?

He should ask the body of government that pays his pension.
In his - new - country of residence he will have to pay the normal income tax on income from his pension.